# Get Project name in URL

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core

When I develop locally (.NET 6.0 - MVC) I have the following base URL:

```
https://localhost:7221/<controller>
```

But when I publish it I have the following base URL:

```
https://<server name>/<application>/<controller>
```

I can't figure out how to get it the same way locally, e.g.

```
https://localhost:7221/<application>/<controller>
```

I'm having problems with AJAX requests who will only work in one of the environments, if I call them with a similar URL:

```
url: "/Ajax/..."
```

Comment: what is <application> exactly? the project name?

Comment: Try generating the `url` using: `@Url.Action` helper on your `AJAX` calls.

Comment: @Url.Action worked like a charm! Put it as an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Url.Action` helper method which generates a fully qualified URL to an action method for the specified action name and route values. So in your case, you can use it in your `AJAX` url call like this:

```
url: '@Url.Action("ActionMethod", "ControllerName")'
```

Note: This method is ONLY accessible in your `.cshtml` file and it would not be accepted in a pure `.js` file(s). If you want your `.js` to access this variable, then you need to define it globally in your `.cshtml` file and then access it your `.js` file(s).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean add project name in the URL?

If so, add project name in route in Program.cs

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "application/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

Result:

[image]

> I'm having problems with AJAX requests who will only work in one of
> the environments, if I call them with a similar URL:url: "/Ajax/..."

[Note] You need to add project name in url too when you use ajax.